# Show div - hide div - wait 15 minutes - repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'm trying to make a javascript, but I'm totally stuck. It is supposed to show a div for 5 seconds, hide it again, wait for 15 minutes, then show it again for 5 seconds, hide it again, wait again and all of that in an infinite loop. I played with some random nummers and this only changes how fast or slow it animates. Anyone got the key? I've been trying full time for the past 2 days. And I should mention I'm a beginner in javascript.

The code so far:

```
setInterval(function(){
     $("#myDiv").show(10000);
     $("#myDiv").hide(10000);
});
```

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for the function that you're trying to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `myDiv` starts hidden, this should do the trick

```
showDiv();

function hideDiv() {
    $("#myDiv").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        showDiv();
    }, 900000); // wait 15 minutes and show it
}

function showDiv() {
    $("#myDiv").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        hideDiv();
    }, 5000); // wait 5 seconds and hide it
}
```

I've created a demo replacing 15 minutes by 5 seconds to make the show/hide effect visible.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v1gn75ou/)